# Building decider and not a decider Turing machines

Tags: grammar, automata, turing-machines, automata-theory

How to make a Turing machine graph which recognizes `all words with an even number of a's` but which is `not a decider` and nothing else. Also, how to make a `decider` Turing machine graph for the same language.

Answer (score 2):

The language of all words with an even number of a's is a regular language, so a simple two-state DFA will accept the language. The same machine is a two-state decider TM that happens not to use the tape for anything except reading input.

To turn such a decider into a recognizer-non-decider (since all deciders are recognizers, too) we must make the TM explicitly recognize strings with an odd number of a's and, rather than simply halt-reject, go into an infinite loop. This can easily be done with a single state.